# If $(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)=(\beta_i,\beta_j)$ for $0<i,j<n+1$, then ${\rm L}(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)\cong {\rm L}(\beta_1, ..., \beta_n)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $V$ be an inner product space over $\mathbb{R}$ with dimension $n$. Let $S$ be a subset of $V$ and $L(S)$ denote the span of $S$.  If $(\alpha_i,\alpha_j)=(\beta_i,\beta_j)$ for every $i, j\in \{1, ...,n\}$, Then
$$L(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)\cong L(\beta_1, ..., \beta_n)?$$

When $n=1$, the result is trivial.

Gram matrix may be useful to prove ${\rm dim} L(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)={\rm dim} L(\beta_1, ..., \beta_n)$, but I do not know how to use it in detail. Can someone give me some hints to this problem?

Comment: What is $L(\cdots)$?

Comment: Here, $L(\cdot\cdot\cdot)={\rm Span}(\cdot\cdot\cdot)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is as follows: note that the spaces in question are the images of the maps $A,B:\Bbb R^n \to V$ given by
$$
A(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1 \alpha_1 + \cdots + x_n \alpha_n, \quad 
B(x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_1 \beta_1 + \cdots + x_n \beta_n.
$$
Using the given information, conclude that $A^*A$ and $B^*B$ are the same map over $\Bbb R^n$ (where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint map of $A$).

Let $U$ denote the common column space of $A^*A$ and $B^*B$. Using the fact that $A$ and $A^*A$ have the same rank, show that $A|_U$ defines an isomorphism between $U$ and the image of $A$, and $B|_U$ defines an isomorphism between $U$ and the image of $B$.

---

Another approach: with $A,B$ as above, note that $\|Ax\|^2 = \|Bx\|^2$ for all $x \in \Bbb R^n$. It follows that $\ker(A) = \ker(B)$, so that $\dim \ker(A) = \dim \ker(B)$, so that $\dim\operatorname{im}(A) = \dim \operatorname{im}(B)$.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, let $\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_r$ and $\beta_1, ..., \beta_s$ be basises of $L(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)$ and $L(\beta_1,...\beta_n)$ respectively, then $r\leq s$ and $s\leq r$ by the theroy of Gram matrix. Therefore $L(\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_n)\cong L(\beta_1, ..., \beta_n)$.

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by “by the theory of Gram matrix”

Comment: @omnomnomnom: A set of vectors are linearly independent if and only if the Gram determinant (the determinant of the Gram matrix) is non-zero by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix

Comment: Why does that allow you to say that $r \leq s$ and $s \leq r$?

Comment: Since both the determinants of Gram matrixs of $\{\alpha_1, ..., \alpha_r\}$ and $\{\beta_1, ..., \beta_r\}$ are non-zero, so $r\leq s$.

Comment: Ok, so to make this into complete argument, we might say the following: "if $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r$ is a basis of $L(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r)$, then the Grammian matrices of $\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_r\}$ and $\{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_r\}$ are both invertible, so the set $\{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_r\}$ is linearly independent, so $\dim L(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n) \leq L(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_n)$. The reverse inequality similarly must hold."

Comment: Yes，you are right.